# Corner Color of a Shape in android

Tags: android, background, shapes

[image]

**I know the solid color and also the corner section but**

> **I want to know how can I fill color of the corner**

Answer (score 4):

Try using `stroke` in your layout file. `stroke` can give you the border colour and width.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:color="@color/yourcolour"
        android:width="4dp"
        />
    //Other adjustments


</shape>
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for

Or if you want something like in your image try the below

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
                <stroke android:color="@android:color/black"
                    android:width="10dp"
                    />

        </shape>

    </item>

    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/black"
                android:width="10dp"
                />

            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="150dp"/>

        </shape>

    </item>



</layer-list>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: stroke is not the problem
I just want to color the corner like red. at the same time body of the shape will be blue.
All will be solid color.

Comment: Did the solution provided seem to solve your problem?

Comment: Actually not. I just found another way to solve the problem(backup plan) with an image. and thank you very much.

Comment: Ohh okay, I thought I had it how you needed. Probably I did not understand properly. Anyway have a nice day and also try to reduce image dependency as it can have bad effect on performance and size of the application. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems you talking about that red colour on above image.
In that case, there is no property which give you such result.
You need to make it logically., Like take 2 views with diff background,

1. Red background with black colour stroke.
2. Sky background overlaping on 1st red view.
   And simply make top view background as rounded with black color stroke. It will provide you the desired design layout.

Make sure you give same stroke to both view so that itlook to be same.

Happy coding.

Comment: thanks. I just fund another way to do this. with an image.